# How does DJB's nistp224 manage to fit compressed points into 224 bits?

Tags: implementation, diffie-hellman, elliptic-curves

DJB's [`nistp224`](http://cr.yp.to/nistp224.html) program purports to be an implementation of elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman relative to the standard NIST P-224 elliptic curve.

To the best of my understanding, ECDH relative to this curve should produce *225*-bit public messages (compressed points consisting of a 224-bit x-coordinate and a 1-bit y-coordinate), which require 29 bytes to encode (in SEC1 format).  Yet somehow `nistp224` manages to produce 28-byte messages, which are therefore one bit short.

How does it do this?  I find the source code utterly unenlightening.

(Rationale for question: It sure would be nice if I could shave a byte off my messages on the wire.)

Comment: "I find the source code utterly unenlightening" - Haha! I'd really like to vote that up two or three more times. How do you like the documentation and custom build system.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you can do ECDH by exchanging only the X coordinates of your public value; as long as the shared secret depends only on the x coordinate, everything works out.

Here's the fundamental property of elliptic curves that makes this work, the x coordinate of $nP$ is only a function of the x coordinate of $P$ (and $n$); it does not depend on the y coordinate of $P$.

So, if the two sides select their secret values as $a$ and $b$, they both compute $aG$ and $bG$.  They then exchange the x-coordinates of those points to the other.  What both sides can do is then compute the x-coordinate of $a(bG) = b(aG) = (ab)G$.  This x-coordinate is the same value on both sides.  Now, neither side knows the y-coordinate of the common point; however, the x-coordinate is sufficient for a shared secret.